# How do I keep asking the user for input if the input wasn't a number?

Tags: java, while-loop, jframe, joptionpane

I'm making a cash register with an "other" option, which allows the user to add an amount through user input. I have done this with a JOptionPane, the "other" button code is the following:

```
private void btnOverigActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String prijs  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Vul een bedrag in");
    try {
        double overigePrijs = Double.parseDouble(prijs);
        if (overigePrijs > 0){
            aantalProducten[6]++;
            totaalPerProduct[6] += overigePrijs;
        }
        huidigePrijsDisplay();
    }
    
    catch (Exception letter){
        while (true){
        prijs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Vul a.u.b. alleen cijfers in.");
        }       
}
```

This while-loop will not close the JOptionPane, even when inputting numbers, how do I loop this correctly?

---

Edit after almost finishing my SE studies:
I was missing an if-statement in my while-loop. What I was trying to do was checking if the input of `prijs` were only numbers and if not, keep showing the dialog. I never got around to fixing this because it's an old project but I should have stated the motivation behind the code more clearly!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does *This while-loop will not close the JOptionPane, even when inputting numbers, how do I loop this correctly?* mean?

Comment: I have put a "while (true)" statement under the catch-exception, but this will not close the inputdialog

Comment: Why not move the `while` outside and move the `try-catch` inside? So when there is no-exception you can just break from the loop.

Comment: If I move the `while` and set it above the `try {` it will completely block the program once I input data

Comment: I don't think so. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear itself. What I assume that if the `try` part does not run as you wish, the `JOptionPane` should reopen and user should be prompted to do it again. If it is so, you can do the following:

Create a method:

```
private void doTheTask(){
String prijs  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Vul een bedrag in");
  try{
  //your task here.
}
catch (Exception letter){
  //Call the method again.
  doTheTask();
}
}
```

And call the method inside your action:

```
private void btnOverigActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    doTheTask();
}
```

Comment: In the top part code, when you type: `catch (Exception letter){
  //Call the method again.
  doTheTask();` are you asking me to call the method with the method itself?

Comment: Yes. Call the method itself.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works! However when I don't enter any input it will also reopen the popup, anyway to change that so it will only happen when I enter letters?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a different approach in your code:

```
  String prijs = "";
  double overigePrijs = -1;
  while (true) {
     prijs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vul een bedrag in");
     if (prijs != null) { // if user cancel the return will be null
        try {
           overigePrijs = Double.parseDouble(prijs);
           break; // Exits the loop because you have a valid number
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
           // Do nothing
        }
     } else {
        // You can cancel here
     }
     // You can send a message to the user here about the invalid input
  }

  if (overigePrijs > 0) {
     aantalProducten[6]++;
     totaalPerProduct[6] += overigePrijs;
  }
  huidigePrijsDisplay();
```

This code will loop until the user enters a valid number and then you can use after the `while` loop. Some improvement may be necessary like a cancel logic or change the message on the second time but the main idea is this.

Comment: So this worked, however when I press OK without entering anything I will also prompt me to fill in a number, any way to change this?

Comment: What do you need in this situation? You can just use an `if (prijs.equals(""))` and do whatever you want.